# Timed mouse cursor focus?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to focus the mouse cursor into a form text box after a web page is loaded using `settimeout`. I did some research and found a script that works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formfocus() {
  document.getElementById('element').focus();
}
window.onload = formfocus;
</script>
```

but it focuses the mouse cursor `onload` and I would like it to load a few seconds after the page is loaded. I am trying to use `settimeout` to fire the the script above, but I am having difficulties. The code below is what I coded. Hopefully someone can help me out with the code below and post an edited working code of what I am trying to accomplish that would be very helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formfocus() {
  document.getElementById('TextArea1').focus();
}
function2 timedFocus() {
setTimeout(function2()formfocus,1000);
}
</script>
<textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" style="position:absolute;left:338px;top:248px;width:150px;height:80px;z-index:0;" rows="2" cols="14"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's probably working try changing the 1000 to 10000. onload is going to fire a little before everything on the page renders so the time between you looking at it and the field gaining focus is a fraction of a second. Just a fyi setTimeout is set in milliseconds so 1000 = 1 sec

Comment: `window.onload=function(){setTimeout(...);}`

Comment: thank Orangepill and passerby for your info and taking the time to look at my issue

Answer (score 1):

There are syntactical errors in the script

1. `function2` is not a valid way to define a function, it should be `function`
2. Your `setTimeout` call is wrong because you have a half cooked function definition there, you can just pass `formfocus` as the first argument
3. You are not calling `timedFocus` anywhere, you can call it on `onload` event

Try

```
function formfocus() {
    document.getElementById('TextArea1').focus();
}
function timedFocus() {
    setTimeout(formfocus,1000);
}

window.onload = timedFocus;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yKgD4/)